# Предупреждение 'Unchecked call' в при создании ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring

Пишу веб-сервис. Использую `@RestController`. Например есть метод который возвращает юзера по id:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity userById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {        
            return new ResponseEntity(entityConverter.userToDTO(userService.getById(id)), HttpStatus.OK);           
}
```

Использую Intellij Idea. Этот метод работает так как мне и надо, но вот IDE пишет предупреждение:

> Warning:(35, 28) Unchecked call to 'ResponseEntity(T, HttpStatus)' as
>   a member of raw type 'org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity'

Как правильно обрабатывать это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Укажите generic type для возвращаемого ResponseEntity:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> userById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(new String("test"), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

В Вашем случаем вместо String будет некий UserDTO.

Comment: Спасибо. Предупреждения ушли. Можно просто написать `new ResponseEntity<>`

Comment: Ну да, с седьмой версии Java можно просто new ResponseEntity<>